# How to retrieve file times with nanosecond precision?

Tags: c, posix, stat, timespec

I've just discovered that the `stat()` call, and the corresponding `struct stat`, does not contain fields for the file times with precision greater than one second. For setting these times, there are a variety of `{f,l}utime{n,}s()` functions, but not for getting.

How then does obtain these times with nanosecond precision, preferably using POSIX API?

Comment: What would the value of nanosecond file time stamps be? A disk is relatively slow device; writing the file to a disk takes a lot longer than a nanosecond. Assuming a single seek and a sector write, the time to write the file is like measured in tens of milliseconds with considerable error dues to small changes in actual physical disk rotation rate, OS distractions, ... I can understand *distinguishing* the time stamps of files so that you can tell that one was written before another; is that what you need?

Comment: I know what I'm after. How soft is this discipline getting? I can't cuddle the computer into doing what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `stat` structure returned by `stat()` itself has been upgraded for POSIX.1-2008.

The `struct stat` structure contains the three modification times as:

```
struct timespec st_atim - Last data access timestamp. 
struct timespec st_mtim - Last data modification timestamp. 
struct timespec st_ctim - Last file status change timestamp.
```

(from [this OpenGroup link here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) under `Headers, <sys/stat.h>`) and that `struct timespec` is defined there (in `<time.h>`) as containing at least:

```
time_t  tv_sec          - Seconds. 
long    tv_nsec         - Nanoseconds.
```

Previously, these three times were `time_t` values with their one-second resolution.

Comment: The `struct stat` you describe here isn't in POSIX: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html . Care to elaborate on the source?

Comment: HP-UX 11 and AIX 5.x do have only `time_t`. Linux (SLES 10) and Solaris 10 have the `struct timespec`, but its name/way to access it is not even uniform. What you quote above comes from Solaris 10 and would not work on any other system. Down-vote stands.

Comment: @Dummy00001, it's in POSIX.1-2008 (issue 7). You're looking at the 2004 edition (issue 6). Follow the link I gave for details, repeated here: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

Comment: @paxdiablo: Thanks. Duly noted. Though it still not very useful to have a solution from version of POSIX which is literally unsupported. At the moment, best portability is achieved by using POSIX 5 (or 6 with some luck). On one side. On another side, it still useless as most file systems do have only seconds precision anyway.

Comment: God save the Queen.. and POSIX.

Comment: Mine has nanosecond precision, with 34 bits left to spare as padding.

Answer (score 1):

Most file systems dont hold such accurate timestamps. From [here](http://www.softpanorama.org/Internals/Filesystems/linux_ext2_ext3.shtml):

> Most file systems, including ext3,
>   include timestamp data that is
>   accurate to a second. Ext4 extends the
>   accuracy of this data to a nanosecond.
>   Some sources also indicate that the
>   ext4 timestamps support dates through
>   April 25, 2514, versus January 18,
>   2038, for ext3